# How to solve linker errors using DSFML2 with D2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, d, sfml, dmd

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu Linux with DMDv2.052, trying to get application working with DSFML2, but I keep running into linker errors.

I built the SFML and CSFML libraries using shared libs + release builds, and installed them, then built the DSFML bindings like this:

```
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/system$ dmd -m64 -lib *.d -of../../../lib/libdsfml-system.a 
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/system$ cd ../window 
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/window$ dmd -m64 -lib *.d -of../../../lib/libdsfml-window.a 
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/window$ cd ../graphics 
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/graphics$ dmd -m64 -lib *.d -of../../../lib/libdsfml-graphics.a 
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/graphics$ cd ../audio 
me@lappy486:~/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/import/dsfml/audio$ dmd -m64 -lib *.d -of../../../lib/libdsfml-audio.a
```

When trying to build a project to use them, I get the following errors:

```
me@lappy486:~/devl/d/Gossamer$ dmd -m64 *.d game/*.d graphics/*.d -L"-L/home/me/devl/sfml2/bindings/d/lib -ldsfml-system -ldsfml-window -ldsfml-graphics -ldsfml-audio" 
collision.o:(.data+0xab0): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics5color12__ModuleInfoZ' 
collision.o:(.data+0xb18): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml6system9exception16LoadingException7__ClassZ' 
collision.o:(.data+0xbe0): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics3all12__ModuleInfoZ' 
collision.o:(.data+0xd38): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics3all12__ModuleInfoZ' 
collision.o:(.data+0xd40): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml6window3all12__ModuleInfoZ' 
collision.o:(.data+0xdd8): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml6system9exception16LoadingException7__ClassZ' 
collision.o:(.data+0xf40): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics3all12__ModuleInfoZ' 
collision.o: In function `_D8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics5image5Image': 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics5image5Image+0x17): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics6sprite6Sprite7__ClassZ' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics5image5Image+0x2a): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics5image5Image7__ClassZ' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics5image5Image+0x67): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC5dsfml8graphics5image5Image' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics5image5Image+0xa3): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBA5WHITEyS5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBA' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics5image5Image6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics5image5Image+0xac): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics6sprite6Sprite6__ctorMFC5dsfml8graphics5image5ImagefffffS5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBAZC5dsfml8graphics6sprite6Sprite' 
collision.o: In function `_D8graphics6screen6Screen5clearMFZv': 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics6screen6Screen5clearMFZv+0xa): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBA5BLACKyS5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBA' 
collision.o: In function `_D8graphics6screen6Screen6__ctorMFAyakkZC8graphics6screen6Screen': 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics6screen6Screen6__ctorMFAyakkZC8graphics6screen6Screen+0x24): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics12renderwindow12RenderWindow7__ClassZ' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics6screen6Screen6__ctorMFAyakkZC8graphics6screen6Screen+0x73): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics12renderwindow12RenderWindow6__ctorMFS5dsfml6window9videomode9VideoModeAyaE5dsfml6window6window5StyleS5dsfml6window6window15ContextSettingsZC5dsfml8graphics12renderwindow12RenderWindow'
collision.o: In function `_D8graphics4text4Font6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics4text4Font': 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics4text4Font6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics4text4Font+0x17): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics4font4Font7__ClassZ' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics4text4Font6__ctorMFAyaZC8graphics4text4Font+0x54): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics4font4Font6__ctorMFAyaZC5dsfml8graphics4font4Font' 
collision.o: In function `_D8graphics4text4Text6__ctorMFC8graphics4text4FontAyakS5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBAZC8graphics4text4Text': 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics4text4Text6__ctorMFC8graphics4text4FontAyakS5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBAZC8graphics4text4Text+0x19): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics4text4Text7__ClassZ' 
graphics/text.d:(.text._D8graphics4text4Text6__ctorMFC8graphics4text4FontAyakS5dsfml8graphics5color4RGBAZC8graphics4text4Text+0x3b): undefined reference to `_D5dsfml8graphics4text4Text6__ctorMFAyaC5dsfml8graphics4font4FontkZC5dsfml8graphics4text4Text' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
--- errorlevel 1
```

Can somebody help with this? I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: what the hell is DSFML2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong, but I'd start by removing any complexities you can:

1. Using `.so` in D is... "problematic", if possible, use static linkage.
2. Try to build it in 32bit mode (64 bit is still alpha last I heard)
3. Try and build a hello world app using the same lib setup.
4. Don't do the link from DMD, do it explicitly via `ld`. (Compile something that already works in verbose mode to get a starting point for the command line you will need.)

Comment: I think you mean `ld`, not `ln`. `ln` is for making filesystem links.